# How to find the equation of lines passing through the origin and perpendicular to the lines $xy-3y^2+y-2x+10=0$

Tags: coordinate-systems

Problem :

How to find the equation of lines passing through the origin and perpendicular to the lines $xy-3y^2+y-2x+10=0$

My working on this :

Two lines are perpendicular if the sum of coefficient of $x^2$ and $y^2$ is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$3y^2-y(x+1)+2x-10=0$$

$$y=\frac{x+1\pm\sqrt{(x+1)^2-12(2x-10)}}{2\cdot3}=\frac{x+1\pm\sqrt{x^2-22x+121}}6=\frac{x+1\pm(x-11)}6$$

Can you determine the gradients from here and reach the destination?

Comment: In the first line I think it should be $x+1$ rather than $x-1$.

Comment: @user103828, If you follow the trail, the rectification was already there, but not in the first line